# How do you accomplish stealth' with the new arrows.meta?

Tags: tikz-arrows

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{pgfcore}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
\resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{
  \begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth']
  \foreach \arrowa [count=\i from 1] in {stealth, Stealth, {Stealth[round]}, >} {
    \path (0.0, {-0.3 * \i}) edge [-\arrowa] (1.0, {-0.3 * \i});
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{document}
```

How do you make `stealth'` using the new `arrows.meta` library?

[image]

Comment: `round` is not round enough for you?

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel: It is good enough :)  The `stealth'` sure looks good though, don't you think?

Comment: Cannot one just copy the definition `\pgfarrowsdeclare{stealth'}{stealth'}...` from `pgflibraryarrows.code.tex`? There are nothing but Bézier curves.

Comment: @Symbol1 Good idea!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @Symbol1, copied this code from pgflibraryarrows and started adapting it to arrows.meta.  length, width, and inset don't work.  It should be called as `Stealthy[round]`.

```
\pgfdeclarearrow{
  name=Stealthy,
  defaults={
    length  = +3.6pt +5.4,
    width'  = +0pt +0.5,
    inset'  = +0pt 0.5,
    line width = +0pt 1 1,
  },
  setup code = {
    \pgfutil@tempdima=0.28pt%
    \advance\pgfutil@tempdima by.3\pgflinewidth%
    \pgfutil@tempdimb=6\pgfutil@tempdima\advance\pgfutil@tempdimb by.5\pgflinewidth%
    \pgfarrowsleftextend{+-\pgfutil@tempdimb}
    \pgfutil@tempdimb=2\pgfutil@tempdima\advance\pgfutil@tempdimb by0.5\pgflinewidth%
    \pgfarrowsrightextend{+\pgfutil@tempdimb}
  },
  drawing code = {
    \pgfutil@tempdima=0.28pt%
    \ifdim\pgfarrowlinewidth=\pgflinewidth\else\pgfsetlinewidth{\pgfarrowlinewidth}\fi
    \advance\pgfutil@tempdima by.3\pgflinewidth%
    \pgfsetdash{}{+0pt}
    \ifpgfarrowroundjoin\pgfsetroundjoin\else\pgfsetmiterjoin\fi
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{2\pgfutil@tempdima}{0\pgfutil@tempdima}}
    \pgfpathcurveto
    {\pgfqpoint{-.5\pgfutil@tempdima}{.5\pgfutil@tempdima}}
    {\pgfqpoint{-3\pgfutil@tempdima}{1.5\pgfutil@tempdima}}
    {\pgfqpoint{-6\pgfutil@tempdima}{3.25\pgfutil@tempdima}}
    \pgfpathcurveto
    {\pgfqpoint{-3\pgfutil@tempdima}{1\pgfutil@tempdima}}
    {\pgfqpoint{-3\pgfutil@tempdima}{-1\pgfutil@tempdima}}
    {\pgfqpoint{-6\pgfutil@tempdima}{-3.25\pgfutil@tempdima}}
    \pgfpathcurveto
    {\pgfqpoint{-3\pgfutil@tempdima}{-1.5\pgfutil@tempdima}}
    {\pgfqpoint{-.5\pgfutil@tempdima}{-.5\pgfutil@tempdima}}
    {\pgfqpoint{2\pgfutil@tempdima}{0\pgfutil@tempdima}}
    \pgfpathclose
    \ifpgfarrowopen\pgfusepathqstroke\else\ifdim\pgfarrowlinewidth>0pt\pgfusepathqfillstroke\else\pgfusepathqfill\fi\fi
  },
  parameters = {
    \the\pgfarrowlinewidth,%
    \ifpgfarrowopen o\fi%
    \ifpgfarrowroundjoin j\fi
  },
}
```

Comment: could you please provide an MWE how to use your solution and an example of rendered output it produces compared to stealth' ?

Comment: @Fry This is the code for `stealth'`