# latex' arrow tip with arrows.meta library

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

Consider the following MWE

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,decorations.pathreplacing, decorations.markings,arrows.meta}
\tikzset{
  big arrow/.style={
    decoration={markings,mark=at position 1 with {\arrow[scale=2.4]{latex'}}},
    postaction={decorate,draw}
    }
  }

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw [big arrow] (0,0) -- (3,0) node[below] {$x$};
  \draw [-{Latex[scale=2]}] (0,0) -- (0,3) node [left] {$y$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I would like to use the `arrows.meta` library to draw an error tip exactly like `latex'`. I read the documentation and apparently there is no `Latex'` in `arrows.meta`.

So, how can I draw in the y axis an arrow like the one in the x axis using the `arrows.meta` library ? (i.e avoiding using the `decoration/postaction` trick).

[image]

Comment: Since, as you said, arrows.new is superseded by arrows.meta, I'm removing my answer. Hopefully that will also give the question more visibility.

Comment: Similar to, not 100% duplicate of, [this post](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/150289/how-do-you-accomplish-stealth-with-the-new-arrows-meta). As I said there: **Cannot one just copy the definition `\pgfarrowsdeclare{latex'}{latex'}...` from `pgflibraryarrows.code.tex`? There are nothing but Bézier curves.**

Comment: @Symbol1 I guess I can copy the definition however I wonder why weren't `stealth'` and `latex'` ported to `arrows.meta`. Is it possible to contact the developers for them to include these arrow styles?

Comment: Probably because some tips are time-consuming for both compiler and PDF viewer. Image that if every `to` construction ends up with 7 curves instead of 1 curve + 6 lines, it will be like 6.9x complex or something. Or image that there are teens of *tips edition* containing different combination of tips (just like Adobe Creative Suite).......

Comment: @Symbol1 I opened a feature request [here](https://sourceforge.net/p/pgf/feature-requests/93/).

Comment: @Symbol1: That's not a good a reason.  Computers are really really fast.  You could easily render millions of arrows per second.

Comment: @NeilG TeX is slow though. (I do not know the exact scale but 1M/sec is a little bit impossible.) On the other hand for renderer, thousands of line segments is the limit. Especially while you are scrolling or zooming, fps goes down significantly.

Comment: 1 million per second is totally reasonable assuming an efficient implementation.  That's 4000 clocks to render an arrow.  As for screen rendering, graphics cards pump out billions of triangles a second, so that should be even faster.  Really, it's no problem.  Any diagram with more than a thousand arrowheads is illegible anyway.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the feature request was declined (https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/issues/617) and hence loading `arrows` library as indicated in the comments seems to be the only solution.